# hatch more than one data serie in a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

When I colored an histogram it accept a list for the different colors, however, for hatching it accept only one value.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


data = [np.random.rand(100) + 10 * i for i in range(3)]
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)

n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(data, 20, histtype='bar',
                        color=['0', '0.33', '0.66'],
                        label=['normal I', 'normal II', 'normal III'],
                        hatch= ['', 'o', '/'])
```

How can I have different hatch for the different series?

Comment: I got the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` so I tried using a tuple instead like `hatch= ('', 'o', '/')` does that do what you want?

Comment: nevermind that applies all three hatches to each one instead of one to each. (like using "o/" as the hatch)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like hist supports multiple hatches for multi-series plots. However, you can get around that with the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt    

data = [np.random.rand(100) + 10 * i for i in range(3)]
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)

n, bins, patches = ax1.hist(data, 20, histtype='bar',
                        color=['0', '0.33', '0.66'],
                        label=['normal I', 'normal II', 'normal III'])

hatches = ['', 'o', '/']
for patch_set, hatch in zip(patches, hatches):
    for patch in patch_set.patches:
        patch.set_hatch(hatch)
```

The object `patches` returned by `hist` is a list of `BarContainer` objects, each of which holds a set of `Patch` objects (in `BarContainer.patches`).  So you can access each patch object and set its hatch explicitly.

or as @MadPhysicist pointed out you can use `plt.setp` on each `patch_set` so the loop can be shortened to:

```
for patch_set, hatch in zip(patches, hatches):
    plt.setp(patch_set, hatch=hatch)
```

Comment: please do not use list comprehension as a one liner nested for loop.   It makes a list of `None` values that it has to throw out afterwards. instead maybe just make a function that takes the patches and hatches and applies them.

Comment: The oneliner looks like it can benefit from `plt.setp`.